# Reading in content from an external command with utf-8

Tags: external-command, encoding

I've got the following vim script to show a perldoc or per man page into a new tab and then rewrap it the text so it's more readable (I have a very wide monitor).

```
nnoremap K :execute "tabnew <bar> read !man " . expand("<cword>") . " <bar><bar>" . " perldoc " . expand("<cword>") . " <bar><bar>" . " perldoc -f " . expand("<cword>") . " <bar><bar> " . " perldoc -q " . expand("<cword>")<cr>1G:set tw=80<cr>gggqGgg`
```

The problem is that UTF-8 characters from the man pages appear to be getting mangled. How do I modify the `read` command or change the tab's settings to properly display these characters?

Comment: try to `:set fenc=utf-8` after the tabnew

Comment: Ah, got it. I had to follow it with a <bar> character.

Comment: @StevieD if you found a solution to your problem you can post an answer to your own question and accept it: that will help further readers encountering the same issue :)